# XAML TextBox - IValueConverter ConvertBack is not called

Tags: xaml, ivalueconverter

I have a TextBox bound to a Converter. Convert ist working fine, ConvertBack is never called.

Shouldn't ConvertBack be called after the TextBox.TextChanged Event ?

Following Code is a simplified example of my problem.

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <converter:Converter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="TestTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10"  
                 Text="{Binding Path=., 
                        Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, 
                        ConverterParameter=Name, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                        Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Simple ValueConverter

```
    public class Converter : IValueConverter
    {
         public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object 
                               parameter, CultureInfo culture)
         {
              return "Yeahhhh";
         }

         public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object 
                                   parameter, CultureInfo culture)
         {
              return "F#*§";
         }
     }
```

Comment: You're going to need to show some more. Please show your Static Resource declaration, the converter code and the property that your text box is bound too.

Comment: I assume that `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is not working because you are not binding to a property of the object but to the object itself.

Comment: Check the Debug Output for errors when running the application